# Java script использование нескольких тернарных операторов (специфический случай)

Tags: javascript

В тесте столкнулся с такой ситуацией:

```
     var y=10;
     var z=3;
     var x=(y%5>0)?(z==3)? z*2 : y+3 :(z<3)? y-z :z++;
     console.log(x); // 3
```

Подскажите какова последовательность вычислений в такой строке. Спасибо!

Comment: слева направо так то `(y % 5 > 0) ? ( (z == 3) ? z * 2 : y + 3 ) : ( (z < 3) ? y - z : z++);`

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в самом последнем условии прописать ++z, то x будет равен 4

Answer (score 2):

Двоеточие всегда относится к последнему перед ним вопросительному знаку. Последовательность действий следующая:

```
x= y%5>0 ? ( z==3 ? z*2
                  : y+3 )
         : ( z<3 ? y-z 
                 : z++ ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114899/) вы можете найти подробный разбор выполнения тернарных операторов в различных языках программирования, в том числе и в javascript.

Порядок в js простой и логичный: сначала проверяется самое левое условие. Если оно верно, то выполняется и возвращается левая часть после первого двоеточия, если не верно, то правая.

Следует отдельно уточнить, что операторы выполняются [справа налево](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

В приведенном вами примере выполнение можно представить примерно такими шагами:

```
(y%5>0)?(z==3)? z*2 : y+3 :(z<3)? y-z :z++; //исходный код
false ? true ? z*2 : y+3 : false ? y-z : z++ //выполнили скобки
//теперь можно выделить три отдельных тернарных оператора: 
//(false ? (true ? z*2 : y+3) : (false ? y-z : z++))
//выполняем их справа налево 
false ? true ? z*2 : y+3 : z++
false ? z*2 : z++
z++
//так как здесь постинкремент - получаем просто "3"
```